# Codeigniter upload file name

Tags: php, codeigniter

Usually we can get the form data in `Codeigniter` by using `$this->input->get('field_name')` or `$this->input->post('field_name')` and that's fine.

In raw `PHP` we use `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` to get the file name that the user trying to upload.

My question is: Is there any `Codeigniter` way to get the name of the file that needs to be uploaded?

I am trying to say that i need to get the file name that the user is trying to upload before trying to save it in my server using `Codeigniter` library instead of using raw `PHP` global `$_FILES` variable.

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        public function do_upload()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                // get the user submitted file name here

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
$file_name =   $upload_data['file_name'];
```

Here is the 2 version doc is for [2](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/file_uploading.html) and for [3](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

if you want to get the file name in backend:

`$this->upload->file_name` It will work based on `system/library/upload.php`
this function.

```
public function data()
{
    return array (
                    'file_name'         => $this->file_name,
                    'file_type'         => $this->file_type,
                    ...
                );
}
```

If you need to get file name...

Before saving to server... you have work in javascript

`<?php echo "<input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' onchange='changeEventHandler(event);' />"; ?>`

onchange event in javascript:

```
<script>
function changeEventHandler(event){
    alert(event.target.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can i call `$this->upload->data()` before calling `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')` ?

Comment: I edited my answer @MahbubulIslam... Are you expecting to get file name before submitting button? or after submit the form

Comment: I am trying to say i need to know the file name the user is trying to upload before trying to upload it in my server.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it more clear. Please check.

Comment: I need the name in backend.

Comment: HI @MahbubulIslam, did you find Codeigniter method to get the file name before uploading it?

Comment: Nope @ArunodaSamarasinghe

Comment: Best I can think of is to add picking up the filename in the browser client with some javascript on form submit; you'll then have access to the filename through $this->input->getpost('...'). But this cannot be trusted (nothing from the browser ever can).

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

// use file_name within the data() the final code will be 

$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data('file_name'));
```